# How to get value from a bootstrap datepicker input with angular 7

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular7, bootstrap-datepicker

I'am coding with angular 7 and bootstrap 4. I used bootstrap datepicker to select date and trying to get data from it .

My html code is like that :

```
<div class="col-lg-8 form-group">
      <input id="startDate" type="text" placeholder="From" 
      class="form-control" bsDatepicker
      [bsConfig]="{ adaptivePosition: true, 
      dateInputFormat:'YYYY-MM-DD'}" (change)="onDateSelect($event)" >
</div>
```

and the JavaScript function is:

```
 selectedStartDate: string;
 onDateSelect(event) {
     this.selectedStartDate = event.target.value;
     console.log(this.selectedStartDate)
   }
```

I'm getting "undefined" as a result.

```
selectedStartDate = undefined
```

can anyone help me to get the value of the selected date from the bootstrap datepicker ?

Comment: <div class="col-lg-8 form-group">
      <input id="startDate" type="text" placeholder="From" 
      class="form-control" bsDatepicker
      [bsConfig]="{ adaptivePosition: true,  
      dateInputFormat:'YYYY-MM-DD'}"
 #value (change)="onDateSelect(value.value)"  >
</div>

//Now this function will have value
selectedStartDate: string;
 onDateSelect(event) {
     this.selectedStartDate = event.target.value;
     console.log(this.selectedStartDate)
   }

Comment: It didn't work !

Comment: Did you tried console the parameter itself ,(event.target.value) this will not work

Comment: Yes and it was "undefined" too. the solution proposed by ahmeticat below worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use with `ngModel` property and `ngModelChange` function.

For example change your html

```
<input id="startDate" type="text" placeholder="From" 
      class="form-control" bsDatepicker [(ngModel)]="selectedStartDate"
      [bsConfig]="{ adaptivePosition: true, 
      dateInputFormat:'YYYY-MM-DD'}" (ngModelChange)="updateMyDate($event)" >
```

and ts file

```
updateMyDate(newDate) {
    console.log(newDate);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked ! But can you please explain the need of "selectedStartDate" in HTML while I'm not really using it in the TS file following your solution?

Comment: I set `selectedStartDate` is a `ngModel` and we can use `ngModelChange`.So angular trigger to our `ngModelChange` when model changed

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-lg-8 form-group">
      <input id="startDate" type="text" placeholder="From" 
      class="form-control" bsDatepicker [(ngModel)]="selectedStartDate"
      [bsConfig]="{ adaptivePosition: true, 
      dateInputFormat:'YYYY-MM-DD'}" >
</div>
```

you will have date in "selectedStartDate"

Comment: I tried that and didn't work. Also I don't really need a two way binding as all what I need is to get the selected date from the template.